# Widgets in Silex with twig

Tags: widget, twig, silex

I wonder how I can make some widget in my twig template.
For example I have the article page and in left sidebar I want to show some other recent articles.
That's how it`s made in [yii](https://arjunphp.com/create-custom-widget-yii-framework/)
But how can I do this with silex or symfony at last.
P.S.: I don't want to pass in every method my articles list that I'm planning to show in sidebar, I hope there is some clever way

Comment: Most custom features in `Twig` are done through [extending twig](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twig/4923/extending-twig#t=201608251912019992834), in your case you could write a function that fetch the articles for you and in your sidebar view you could do sthing like: `{% for article in get_recent_articles() %}...{% endfor %}` This way you don't need to pass anything to the current controller(s)

Comment: but what if I don't wont to use functional programming, what if I wont use oop. what if I wont to use class ArticleController where I have my get_recent_articles method.

Comment: No need to rewrite code, you can just use the existing class to fetch your articles as seen [here](http://pastebin.com/wzXFRE4V)